# sonar .net plugin fails for mixed languages

Tags: .net, vb.net, code-analysis, sonarqube

I am trying to run Sonar on a .net solution,
which contains mainly c# projects, with one legacy vb.net project.
Sonar fails to run with this error message:

**Language with key 'vbnet' not found.**

I've tried to exclude the project in the config file using:
**sonar.skippedModules**  , but that didn't help.

The only solution I've found so far is the Vb.Net [plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/vb-net/), 
which costs a LOT of money.

Would appreciate any help in resolving/working around this issue.

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried with a sample solution that contains both C# and VB.NET projects, and using the "sonar.skippedModules" works perfectly. There's a [specific FAQ about exlcuding modules in .NET solution using this property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Running+an+Analysis+on+a+C%23+Solution#RunninganAnalysisonaC#Solution-Settingexclusions) that you probably haven't read yet and which will certainly help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. i do see that the project is skipped in the log., but still i get the error. i'm guessing it is because it is still accessed through other projects in the solution, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you probably have other VB.NET projects in your solution.

Comment: you misunderstood me. I have only one vb project. it is of course refrenced by c# projects.is it possible that sonar fails because of this dependency even though the vb project is excluded?  thanks

Comment: No, it should not fail (at least not with the error message you gave).

Comment: OK , there was indeed another hidden vb project. thank you very much

Comment: The FAQ link in the answer is no longer working. This page in the documentation provides information that I think is at least similar: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus